# Cannot read "one to many" Relation with go-pg

Tags: postgresql, go, join, has-many, go-pg

I am trying to implement a little state machine with go and store my states in a postgres db.

i created my database like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE state_machines
(
   id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
   initial_state TEXT NOT NULL,
   "name" TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE state_machine_states
(
   state_machine_id uuid NOT NULL REFERENCES state_machines(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   "name" TEXT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(state_machine_id, "name")
);
```

```golang
// StateMachine is the DB schema
type StateMachine struct {
    ID           *uuid.UUID                `pg:"id,pk,type:uuid,default:uuid_generate_v4()"`
    Name         string                    `pg:"name"`
    InitialState string                    `pg:"initial_state"`
    States       []*StateMachineState      `pg:"fk:state_machine_id"`
}

// StateMachineState is the DB schema
type StateMachineState struct {
    StateMachineID uuid.UUID `pg:"state_machine_id,fk"`
    Name           string    `pg:"name"`
}
```

I am using go-pg 9.2 and i am trying to load a state machine and a list of its states from the "States" relation.

My function to load the state machines looks like this:

```golang
func (cep *repository) GetStateMachines() ([]*StateMachine, error) {
    stateMachines := []*StateMachine{}

    err := cep.db.Model(&stateMachines).
        Relation("States").
        Relation("Transitions").
        Select()

    return stateMachines, err
}
```

If I execute it, I always get the error message `Error reading state machine: model=StateMachine does not have relation="States"`

I have done similar relations before and they worked and now, I cannot get it to work again :(

Comment: in your table `state_machines` you have not added `States` column. just add the column, it should work

Comment: If there is one entity in table A that has a list of entities stored in table B, then the reference is made in table B. The other way around, you would need a list of ids in table A.

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading to v10 which fully supports relations: https://pg.uptrace.dev/orm/has-many-relation/

Comment: thank you for that info. i need to get some "time budget" from my customer to test it and if it works, i will flag it is correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

See if there is .Debug() function in go-pg for a query.
I use https://gorm.io/ , and there is a Debug funcion, that returns all of the SQL queries.
When i see what queries are send, i log in postgresql and try them manually to see a more detailed error.

Comment: That error happens, before the query is been created. It is an error in the go-pg not from the postgresdb.